# I wan redirect link post search to search product woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, search

Search results link for the post : https://domain.com/?s=item+item

I want when clicking search, the article search link automatically redirects to the product woocommerce search link is:
https://domain.com/?s=item+item&post_type=product

We hope you help, thank you !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think, you just need to add below code on above the submit button code in `searchform.php` file.

```
<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product" />
```

Comment: Thank you verry much,  The code works perfectly! (@ _ @)